# render two UILabels in CGContext without overlapping

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uikit, uilabel

Hello i try to render two labels in one CGContext to get an UIImage - one above the other. However the code is ignoring the origins of the CGRects. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
// frames with positions and bounds
let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 64, height: 64)
let upperFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 64, height: 40)
let lowerFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 40, width: 64, height: 24)

// settings of lower label
let lowerLabel = UILabel(frame: lowerFrame)
lowerLabel.textAlignment = .center
lowerLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 0.0)
lowerLabel.textColor = .black
lowerLabel.font = nameLabel.font.withSize(15.0)
lowerLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
lowerLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 1.0/nameLabel.font.pointSize
lowerLabel.text = "Monatsende"

// settings of upper label
let upperLabel = UILabel(frame: upperFrame)
upperLabel.textAlignment = .center
upperLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 0.0)
upperLabel.textColor = .black
upperLabel.font = upperLabel.font.withSize(15.0)
upperLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
upperLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 1.0/upperLabel.font.pointSize
upperLabel.text = "2500 €"

// draw alltogether
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(frame.size)
if let currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
  lowerlabel.layer.render(in: currentContext)
  upperLabel.layer.render(in: currentContext)
  let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
  return image
}
```

the result is, that both labels are overlapping each other:

[image: result]

as i understand it the two labels should be clearly distinguishable from one another.

Comment: No need for labels. Use `NSAttributedString` and one of its `draw` methods.

Comment: And how can i get NSAttributedString to automatically fit in the given CGRect. What i can achieve for the uilabel with adjustsFontSizeToWidth...

Comment: I overlooked that need. You would need to determine the proper font size yourself.

Comment: yeah, i'm on that. thank you for your input!